# Transactions inside tasks of ManagedScheduledExecutorService on TomEE 7.0.0?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7, apache-tomee, tomee-7

## Context

I want to schedule recurring background tasks using `ManagedScheduledExecutorService`. I get my `Runnable`s/`Callable`s via an `Instance`, so I have injection capabilities available inside my tasks.

My application runs on `TomEE 7.0.0-SNAPSHOT webprofile`.

## Problem

As these tasks are accessing the database they need a transaction. However, inside the `Runnable`/`Callable` no transaction is active.

### User transaction

The [documentation for ManagedScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html) states that

> If a transaction is required, use a javax.transaction.UserTransaction instance. A UserTransaction instance is available (...) by requesting an injection of a UserTransaction object using the Resource annotation.

However, the injected

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction userTransaction;
```

is `null` when invoking the task.

### Stateless bean

Another approach I took was to inject a stateless EJB into my task, hoping that this would create a transaction for me.

This resulted in the following exception on startup:

```
SEVERE: CDI Beans module deployment failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no interface to proxy for ejb StatelessEjb, is this is a MDB maybe you shouldn't use a scope?
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiEjbBean.createEjb(CdiEjbBean.java:252)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiPlugin.getSessionBeanProxy(CdiPlugin.java:224)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getEjbOrJmsProxyReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:951)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:777)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:651)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.AbstractInjectable.inject(AbstractInjectable.java:111)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableConstructor.createParameters(InjectableConstructor.java:109)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.InjectableConstructor.doInjection(InjectableConstructor.java:72)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.newInstance(InjectionTargetImpl.java:190)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.InjectionTargetImpl.produce(InjectionTargetImpl.java:173)
    at org.apache.webbeans.portable.AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducer.java:172)
    at org.apache.webbeans.component.AbstractOwbBean.create(AbstractOwbBean.java:127)
    at org.apache.webbeans.component.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:67)
    at org.apache.webbeans.context.DependentContext.getInstance(DependentContext.java:68)
    at org.apache.webbeans.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:124)
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:785)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.instance.InstanceImpl.create(InstanceImpl.java:306)
    at org.apache.webbeans.inject.instance.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:123)
(...)
```

## Test case

I've created a small [test case project on Github](https://github.com/schroenser/ejb-in-executorservice-test). It contains two branches, illustrating the problems mentioned above.

## Questions

- Shouldn't the `@Stateless` EJB work normally as all instances are obtained using injection?
- Why does `@Resource` injection for the `UserTransaction` fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CDI to get it should fix it:

```
@Inject
private UserTransaction userTransaction;
```

edit: the issue has been fixed for @Resource case: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-1672

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why the stateless EJB doesn't work?

Comment: likely the same issue as the @Resource one (used too early, if you use a singleton startup all your code should be fine)

Comment: Thank you. I updated both branches of my test case according to your input.

Comment: @rmannibucau perhaps offtopic, but since this question is about TomEE 7 and it still hasn't been released, is there any target release date for 7?

Comment: This is mainly a legal question but for a plain tomee - and from user point of view - OpenJPA is the big thing to make moving (from JPA 2.0 to 2.1) but using plume you have almost everything of EE 7 already (with eclipselinks instead of OpenJPA).